# How generate and insert ssh public key definition in cloudfromation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, aws-cloudformation, aws-glue

I have generated ssh key via amazon web console. But how to use it for creating glue developer endpoint?

Consider the following code snippet:

```
    IAMRole:
      Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
      DeletionPolicy: "Delete"
      Properties:
        AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            -
              Effect: "Allow"
              Principal:
                Service: "glue.amazonaws.com"
              Action: "sts:AssumeRole"
        ManagedPolicyArns:
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
          - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSGlueServiceRole"
        MaxSessionDuration: 3600
        Path: "/role/"
        # PermissionsBoundary: String
        # Policies: Json
        RoleName: "GlueDevEndpoint"

    GlueDevEndpoint:
      Type: AWS::Glue::DevEndpoint
      DeletionPolicy: "Delete"
      Properties:
        EndpointName: MyEndpointName
        GlueVersion: "1.0"
        NumberOfNodes: 2
        PublicKey: >
          ---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
          Comment: "imported-openssh-key"
          AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
          BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
          CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
          DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
          EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
          ---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
        RoleArn: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn
```

I got error:

```
An error occurred: GlueDevEndpoint - Invalid SSH RSA public key. ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com" (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInputException.
```

I have tried to put a content from:

1. `pem` file downloadeed from aws console.
2. extract public/private key parts via putty and use them
3. extract public key via commands:
   openssl rsa -in my-key.pem -pubout > my-key.pubrsa
4. extract public key via commands:
   ssh-keygen -y -f my-key.pem > my-key2.pubrsa

Putting content from all these files lead to same error. I think that public key should be generated to have header like
`-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----` but all of approaches before gives me public keys with different headers:
`-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`,`---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----`,`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Adding on to what @Cherry mentioned, Glue requires the public RSA key to require an email address.

Generate the private public key pair with an email ID.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "user@email.com"
```

This generates the public key in the following format.

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzU6mXo= user@email.com
```

Upload the above public key to AWS Glue when provisioning the endpoint.

Comment: Good point mate, the -C is for comment. The AWS Glue ssh key manager must require it, most likely to identify the user.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to use key in fomat like:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA user@email.com
```

**Do not forget** to include you email at the end! Without this amazon will fail with error.

```
GlueDevEndpoint:
  Type: AWS::Glue::DevEndpoint
  DeletionPolicy: "Delete"
  Properties:
    EndpointName: MyEndpointName
    GlueVersion: "1.0"
    NumberOfNodes: 2
    PublicKey: "ssh-rsa AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA user@email.com"
    RoleArn: !GetAtt IAMRole.Arn
```